# Struggling to correctly implement a custom rails controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to implement a controller method where one account sends a sum of money to another account. The code in `accnts_controller` is as follows:

```
def donate(amt, client)
    if creator?
      raise 'Only Patron accounts can donate'
    else
      @client = Accnt.find(client)
      @client.balance += amt
      @accnt.balance -= amt
      @client.save
      @accnt.save
    end
  end
```

(note: In my controller, I have a before action which sets up the `@accnt` object)

To do this, I have written the following custom route:

```
patch 'accnts/:id/donate' => 'accnts#donate'
```

I have been having a couple of problems in implementing this method, but far and away the largest is that I do not know how to write a cURL request which can pass values to the `amt` and `client` arguments. I almost exclusively use cURL to test the efficacy of my back end, as the program I am in did not teach us how to use rails views. How can I go about writing a curl request to test my method?

EDIT: my full controller code. This was generated with a scaffold and has been slightly modified

```
class AccntsController < OpenReadController
  before_action :set_accnt, only: %i[show update donate destroy]
  # GET /accnts
  def index
    @accnts = Accnt.all
    render json: @accnts
  end
  # GET /accnts/1
  def show
    render json: @accnt
  end
  # POST /accnts
  def create
    if current_user.accnt
      raise 'Already has an account'
    else
      @accnt = Accnt.new(accnt_params)
      @accnt.user = current_user
      if @accnt.save
        render json: @accnt, status: :created
      else
        render json: @accnt.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
      # render json: @accnt, status: :created, location: @accnt if @accnt.save
    end
  end
  # PATCH/PUT /accnts/1
  def update
    if @accnt.update(accnt_params)
      render json: @accnt
    else
      render json: @accnt.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
  # amt is the amount to be sent from the patron to the client, client is the client ID
  def donate(amt, client)
    # furthermore, I cannot say for certain whether this method of passing parameters is viable in rails
    if creator?
      raise 'Only Patron accounts can donate'
    else
      # Very easily could be logical errors here
      @client = Accnt.find(client)
      @client.balance += amt
      @accnt.balance -= amt
      @client.save
      @accnt.save
    end
  end
  # DELETE /accnts/1
  def destroy
    @accnt.destroy
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    # To be used as a before method to determine whether or not the account in
    # question is a creator account
    def creator?
      creator
    end
    def set_accnt
      @accnt = Accnt.find(params[:id])
    end
    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def accnt_params
      params.require(:accnt).permit(:user_id, :user_name, :balance, :creator, :content_type, :content_list)
    end
end
```

As for the Curl request, I haven't really written it out beyond this:

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/accnts"
curl "${API}${URL_PATH}/${ID}/donate" \
  --include \
  --request PATCH \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Token token=$TOKEN" \
  --data 
echo
```

Comment: Can you add your controller and the cURL request you're making?

Comment: How are `amt` and `client` defined? (What parameters is it using?) And please show what your current cURL attempt looks like, otherwise we have no way of knowing what you have done wrong.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the requested code. @TomLord;  amt is a float which modifies the balance property of both the account calling the donate method and the account it targets, while client is the id property of the account being targeted for donation. As you can see, my curl request is not complete yet, as I do not know how to pass values to the method arguments.

Comment: Umm.. Yeah, that's kinda the crux of it. Your controller definition doesn't make sense -- you need to pass those as HTTP parameters, not method arguments. E.g. `params[:amt]` and `params[:client_id]`. Once your controller is fixed, I think you'll find the cURL command quite easy to write.

Comment: By the way, it's common practice in Rails to spell words properly and not skip vowels to abbreviate things. I definitely would have written all this as `account`, not `accnt`.

Comment: I was able to get my method to work, thank you! As for the name of the `accnt` resource, I created an `account` resource, then overwrote it, renaming it something else in my database. When I tried to rescaffold and migrate the account method, I found myself facing constant errors. In order to avoid being bogged down, I simply dropped the 'ou' and moved forward. Once I can get my core functions down, I intend to go back and rename the structure.

Comment: Keep in mind code like this is subject to race conditions so be sure to fix it if you're handling real money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the working method code and curl request n my controller:

```
def donate
  if @accnt.creator
    raise 'Only Patron accounts can donate'
  else
    client = params[:client_id]
    amt = params[:amt]
    # Very easily could be logical errors here
    @client = Accnt.find(client)
    @client.balance += amt
    @accnt.balance -= amt
    @client.save
    @accnt.save
  end
end
```

And my (hideously hardcoded) cURL request:

```
API="http://localhost:4741"
URL_PATH="/accnts"
ID="2"
TOKEN="BAhJIiU2ZDA2MGI4YzZkZjFkMmRkYTBkMWI3ZmRjMmRiMTZlYgY6BkVG--e55aee8e39c0cdd0bf944fa66661f06930037ba1"
curl "${API}${URL_PATH}/${ID}/donate" \
  --include \
  --request PATCH \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Token token=$TOKEN" \
  --data '{
    "client_id": 1,
    "amt": 10.0
  }'
echo
```

Comment: There you're defining `amt` but you're not using it d00medman. Don't you need to `find` the `amt` object, or are you using the scaffold's method `set_amt`?

Comment: `amt` is not a property of account, it an amount by which the balance of the payer and payee accounts will be modified by.